# Samples from scaled inverse chisquare distribution

Tags: r, distribution, geor

I want to generate sa scaled-inv-chisquared distribution in R. I know `geoR` have a R function for generating this. But I want to use gamma-distribution to generate this. 
I think this two are equivalent:

```
X ~ rinvchisq(100,  df=d, scale=s)
1/X ~ rgamma(100, shape=d/2, scale=2/(d*s))
```

isn't it? Can there be any numerical problem due this due to extreme values?

Comment: Wikipedia has a nice discussion on this

Comment: What sort of problem are you concerned about? The chi^2 distribution apparently does not behave badly as the denominator in 1/X. It's well known that chi^2 is a special case of gamma.

Answer (score 3):

More specifically you would need `X <- rinvchisq(...)` and `X <- 1/rgamma(...)` (the `~` notation works this way in programs such as WinBUGS, and in statistics notation, but not in R).  If you look at the code of `geoR::rinvchisq`, the relevant part is just

```
return((df * scale)/rchisq(n, df = df))
```

so if you have problems taking the reciprocal of very large or small chi-squared deviates you'll be in trouble anyway (although `rchisq` is internally using `.External(C_rchisq, n, df)`, which falls through to C code, presumably for efficiency in this special case, rather than calling `rgamma`).  If I were you I would go ahead and superimpose densities of some test samples just to make sure I hadn't screwed up the arithmetic or parameterization somewhere ...

For what it's worth there are also `rinvgamma()` functions in a variety of packages (`library(sos); findFn("rinvgamma")`)

Comment: +1 I wonder if the OP intended `~` as "is distributed as", bu used the somewhat unfortunate code markup here. The `1/X` line suggests this as it wouldn't be valid BUGS code either.